# What is the memory layout of an std::multimap?

Tags: c++

I'm decompiling an ARMv7 Android game by hand (I have the C++ headers to the game), and I've come across an:

```
std::multimap<float, AppPlatformListener*, std::less<float>, std::allocator<std::pair<const float, AppPlatformListener*>>> listeners;
```

and I must know, what is the memory layout of such an object? I've never used a multimap in C++ before.

Comment: `std::multimap` is typically implemented as a binary-search-tree. The memory layout of the object will depend on the exact STL library version used.

Comment: What's a binary search tree?

Comment: Every implementation I've seen uses a particular kind of binary search tree called a [red black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree).

Comment: A binary tree is built from nodes which contain a key (and in the case of a map, also a value), and two pointers to child nodes. A red-black tree has some particular rules how those child nodes are managed, but that does not change the nature of the binary tree.